Functor induced on Verdier quotient from an exact functor remains exact?
Let $\mathcal S$ be a thick subcategory  of a triangulated category $\mathcal T$. If $F: \mathcal T \to \mathcal T$ is an exact functor such that $F(\mathcal S)\subseteq \mathcal S$, then we have an induced functor $\widetilde F: \mathcal T/\mathcal S \to \mathcal T/\mathcal S$. My question is: Is $\widetilde F$ also exact?

Does https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05RJ answer your question?
